# Scope issue in C++

Tags: c++

I have following code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   addition(....);
}

constexpr static uint64_t addition (int a, int b) {
 .....
}
```

I get error as:

> error: ‘addition’ was not declared in this scope

What is wrong here?

Comment: You need to forward declare `addition` or move the definition to before it is encountered in `main()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between declaring functions before or after main()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21718361/whats-the-difference-between-declaring-functions-before-or-after-main)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You try this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// function declaration
constexpr static uint64_t addition (int a, int b);

int main()
{
   addition(....);
}

constexpr static uint64_t addition (int a, int b) {
   .....
}
```

You need to declare the method before `main()` or you can define the complete method before `main()`.